# this keyword scope and object returned

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js with socket.io and node-mysql.
I have an user class to login and manipulate users.
In the constructor I make a query to the db.

```
function user(u,pass,connection,callback){
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? && `password`= ? LIMIT 1",[u,pass], function(err,result)
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        this.id = false;
    }
    else {
        if(result.length > 0){
            var row = result[0];
            this.socket = null;
            this.id = row.id;
            this.inuse = null;
        }
        else 
            this.id=false;
    }
    callback(this);

    });
}
```

I must make a callback function because making a query to the db is async. but, when I use the this key word i append properties to the connection instance and not to my new object im creating.
Also, when I pass the this keyword to the callback im passing 'connection' and not 'user', so I dont have my object.
Does someone know a solution to this problem?

I use it like this

```
        user_fac(username,password,connection, function(u){
            console.log(u);
            if(u.id){
                clients[u.id] = u;

            }
            else {
                //throw error
            }
        });
```

Comment: What object? Why would `this` be anything other than the connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the object you're referring to is the `user()` function, and you can store `this` from another scope in a variable, and add to that.

```
function user(u,pass,connection,callback){
    var self = this;

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? && `password`= ? LIMIT 1",[u,pass], function(err,result)
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            self.id = false;
        } else {
            if(result.length > 0){
                var row = result[0];
                self.socket = null;
                self.id = row.id;
                self.inuse = null;
            } else {
                self.id=false;
            }
        }
        callback(self);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stash it before hand.

```
function user(u,pass,connection,callback){
  var that = this  /// <---- stash it in the closure

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? && `password`= ? LIMIT 1",[u,pass], function(err,result) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      that.id = false;   // <----- use that instead of this
    } else {
      if(result.length > 0){
          var row = result[0];
          that.socket = null;
          that.id = row.id;
          that.inuse = null;
      }
      else {
          that.id=false;
      }
     callback(that);

  });
}
```